# Obj-C - Set imageview background color programatically with custom int values?

Tags: arrays, objective-c

I'm trying to set the background color of my imageview with integers inside of a string passed from another ViewController (self.receivedData.text). I'm using the following code to separate the values in the string; the string returned (for example) is: 100, 210, 70, and is then broken down into an array. This all works, however:

**a)** I'm only able to access the first value in the separated string (array; attempting to access the other two values crashes my app, even though they exist) and

**b)** when I try and set these values to the appropriate green: blue: and red: values, my imageview remains empty?

How can I fix this?

**ViewController.m**

```
 NSArray *array = [self.receivedData.text componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSLog(@"Show the count %lu", (unsigned long)[array count]);
        
       for (NSUInteger i=1; i< array.count; i++) {
           
            NSString *comp1 = array[0];
                  NSString *comp2 = array[1];
                  NSString *comp3 = array[2];
                  
                  NSInteger red = [comp1 integerValue];
                  NSLog(@"What is comp1 %ld", red);
                  NSInteger green = [comp2 integerValue];
                   NSLog(@"What is comp2 %ld", green);
                  NSInteger blue = [comp3 integerValue];
                   NSLog(@"What is comp3 %ld", blue);

                  
                   NSLog(@"In the array you will find %@", array);
               
                   [self.colorSwatch setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0]];

     
           
            NSLog(@"content @%",array[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Any build warnings? Is "Show the count 3" loggged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty sure you are crashing because

```
NSLog(@"content %@", array[i]);
```

is exceeding maximum index of expected 3 with an index of 4 at least in the last loop.

you also access the indexes directly in a for loop based on the amount of indexes in your array. So you are actually doing 3 times the same thing.

instead it can be written so..

```
NSString *text = @"100, 210, 70,";

NSArray *array = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
//NSArray *shouldResultIn = @[@"100",@" 210",@" 70",@""];
```

so you want to be sure you never access indexes higher then array.count but make sure you have at least indexes 0,1,2 available

```
if (array.count>2) {
    
    CGFloat colorFactor = 1.0f/256.0f;
    CGFloat r = colorFactor * (CGFloat)[(NSString *)array[0] integerValue];
    CGFloat g = colorFactor * (CGFloat)[(NSString *)array[1] integerValue];
    CGFloat b = colorFactor * (CGFloat)[(NSString *)array[2] integerValue];
    // why multiplication? 
    // because you don't want devision by 0 -> error.
    
    UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1.0];
    
    [self.colorSwatch setBackgroundColor:bgColor];

    NSLog(@"color %f %f %f",r, g, b);
    if (array.count>3) NSLog(@"not used separatedString in array %@",array[3]);
}
```

you could also write

```
if (array.count==3) { ... }
```

to make sure its only processed if there are exact 3 indexes.

But thats still not safe against letters in the string. Think you have made that sure in the input method of your `self.receivedData.text`

also `UIColor-colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` expects `CGFloat` parameters, converting to NSInteger is not fitting here.
A little helper formula helps out if your integers are defined with a maximum of 256 colors each color tone.